# Simulate click with javascript with no element ID

Tags: javascript, click, simulate

```
<button 
   type="button" 
   class="blue" 
   data-events="click:onAddNote" 
   data-events-target="cpoe-LabResultDetailView"
>
   Add Note
</button>
```

I'm trying to simulate / prompt a click of this button when I press a shortcut key sequence. However, I haven't been successful with anything other than through the class "blue", which works but also activates something else. How do I target the "data-events" or "data-events-target"?

Is there a way to something similar to:
`$("click:onAddNote").trigger("click");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use querySelector and select the button with its attributes

```js
var button = document.querySelector('[data-events="click:onAddNote"]');
button.onclick = ()=>console.log('Clicked');
button.click()
```

```html
<button 
   type="button" 
   class="blue" 
   data-events="click:onAddNote" 
   data-events-target="cpoe-LabResultDetailView"
>
   Add Note
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just this?

```
const button = docuemnt.querySelector('button')
button.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to select the `<button>` element.

###### Method-1

In the example below, the `click` event is fired by selecting the first `<button>` element with the `.blue` class style applied.

```js
let button = document.getElementsByClassName('blue');

button[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log("clicked");
});
```

```html
<button type="button" class="blue">Add Note</button>
```

###### Method-2

The `click` event of the `<button>` element with the `.blue` class style applied using **jQuery** can be rendered as follows:

```js
$(".blue").on('click', function(event) {
  console.log("clicked");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="blue" data-events="click:onAddNote" data-events-target="cpoe-LabResultDetailView">Add Note</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Targeting the "data-events" attribute is simple, like this ...

```js
$('button[data-events="click:onAddNote"]').on('click', function(){
  console.log('clicked!');
});
```

```html
<button 
   type="button" 
   class="blue" 
   data-events="click:onAddNote" 
   data-events-target="cpoe-LabResultDetailView"
>
   Add Note
</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

See the jquery documentation for more information on running handlers -- [Here](https://learn.jquery.com/events/triggering-event-handlers/)